# A stronger Cauchy-Schwarz in infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2458850/tighter-inequality-than-cauchy-schwarz-inequality) MSE and question and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301844/a-strengthening-of-the-cauchy-schwarz-inequality) MO question, stronger variants of the classical Cauchy-Schwarz inequality have been suggested in finite dimensional spaces. Can we find similar results for infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces such as $L^2$?

Comment: This inequality makes sense only of your vector spaces are real. For real $\ell^2$ or real $L^2$ similar inequalities can be obtained by passing to the limit in finite dimensional inequalities.

Comment: Can you demonstrate such an example?

Comment: What example? For $\ell^2$, just replace finite sums with infinite sums.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: I agree that it's very simple on $\ell^2$. For $L^2$-spaces, though, the question seems to be much more subtle (starting with the fact that $L^2$ is not contained in $L^4$).

Comment: Schwarz, please.

Comment: Would the person who voted to close as "not about research level mathematics" kindly explain their objections? When the post in the second link was asked and answered, I thought for a while about the $L^2$-case, too, but I did not even come close to any satisfactory answer. So I do not find this question simple or elementary by any means.

Comment: For functions which do not belong to $L^4$, this inequality has no sense.